# Wordpress -> how to reload "addtoanny" plugin after AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax, wordpress

Hej, I'm have my custom Wordpress template, where using this plugin for sharing different things. https://www.addtoany.com . But when I'm using AJAX to load posts it needs to be reloaded. Documentation says that this

```
jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'post-load' );
```

should resolve the problem, but nothing happens. I'm using Angularjs and PHP to load posts. In PHP when retrieving posts from DataBase I have something like this

```
$some_var = do_shortcode('[addtoany]');
```

I have no idea how to reload it.